# Pressing tab does not select MenuButton in ChakraUI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I started pressing tab to navigate in my page, but noticed that the Menu button was not being selected, it gets jumped straight over.
This is my menu component:

```
<Menu>
  <MenuButton
    as={IconButton}
    aria-label="Pages"
    icon={<HamburgerIcon />}
    variant="outline"
    _focus={{ boxShadow: "outline" }}
  />
  <MenuList>
    <MenuItem>
      <Link href="/about">About us</Link>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
      <Link href="/our-work">Our Work</Link>
    </MenuItem>
    {!isLargerThan500 && <MenuItem>Contact us</MenuItem>}
  </MenuList>
</Menu>
```

What do you think might be the problem?